# NVM Install Error: Profile not found. Tried ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, and ~/.profile.

Tags: node.js, nvm

I JUST wiped and reformatted my entire Macbook Retina drive to start from scratch,
installed homebrew,
installed xcode and accepted terms and conditions,
went to install nvm with `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash` and got the following error:

```
=> nvm is already installed in /Users/dillon/.nvm, trying to update using git
=> => Compressing and cleaning up git repository

=> Profile not found. Tried ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, and ~/.profile.
=> Create one of them and run this script again
   OR
=> Append the following lines to the correct file yourself:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

`echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` if that's any help.

I tried opening an [issue on github](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1837) but haven't received a response

Any idea what I can do to get nvm and node properly running?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the info in the title! I would try source: `source ~/.bash_profile` first if you haven't already.

Comment: `-bash: /Users/dillon/.bash_profile: No such file or directory`

Comment: I ran `touch ~/.bash_profile` and things seem to be working. Is that the right thing to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Didn't read this from the nvm install instructions. It fixed my problem.

> Note: On OS X, if you get nvm: command not found after running the
>   install script, one of the following might be the reason:-
>
> ```
> your system may not have a [.bash_profile file] where the command is set up. Simply create one with touch ~/.bash_profile and run the
> ```
>
> install script again
>       you might need to restart your terminal instance. Try opening a new tab/window in your terminal and retry.

Comment: That's exactly what the error message is telling you, too. *"Create one of them and run this script again"*

Answer (score 1):

1. `touch ~/.bash_profile`
2. Rerun the nvm install command
3. Completely Quit and reopen the terminal
4. `nvm -v` should now work correctly

The problem is bash doesn't know where nvm is. You need a bash_profile file to tell bahs where to look. Installing nvm will not create this file for you, but it will insert the instructions that tells it where to look.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming for Windows Git Bash, you want to add the missing file (e.g.  `.bashrc`) to your `%USERPROFILE%` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The following command solved my problem:

`sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/david/.config`

Note: Change 'david' in the path for your user.